# How to click on svg icon in Robotframework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, svg, robotframework

I need to click on an svg icon but it always gives me an error. Below I detail my code

click element  xpath=//path[contains(@d,'M400 32H48A48 48 0 0 0 0 80v352a48 48 0 0 0 48 48h137.25V327.69h-63V256h63v-54.64c0-62.15 37-96.48 93.67-96.48 27.14 0 55.52 4.84 55.52 4.84v61h-31.27c-30.81 0-40.42 19.12-40.42 38.73V256h68.78l-11 71.69h-57.78V480H400a48 48 0 0 0 48-48V80a48 48 0 0 0-48-48z')]

### html

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/zzz/" aria-label="Facebook" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" style="--color: #557dbc; --background-color: transparent;" class="ast-builder-social-element ast-inline-flex ast-facebook footer-social-item">

<span class="ahfb-svg-iconset ast-inline-flex svg-baseline"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path d="M400 32H48A48 48 0 0 0 0 80v352a48 48 0 0 0 48 48h137.25V327.69h-63V256h63v-54.64c0-62.15 37-96.48 93.67-96.48 27.14 0 55.52 4.84 55.52 4.84v61h-31.27c-30.81 0-40.42 19.12-40.42 38.73V256h68.78l-11 71.69h-57.78V480H400a48 48 0 0 0 48-48V80a48 48 0 0 0-48-48z"></path></svg></span></a>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512">
<path d="M400 32H48A48 48 0 0 0 0 80v352a48 48 0 0 0 48 48h137.25V327.69h-63V256h63v-54.64c0-62.15 37-96.48 93.67-96.48 27.14 0 55.52 4.84 55.52 4.84v61h-31.27c-30.81 0-40.42 19.12-40.42 38.73V256h68.78l-11 71.69h-57.78V480H400a48 48 0 0 0 48-48V80a48 48 0 0 0-48-48z"></path>
</svg>
```

I'm trying to click on an icon svg

Comment: Please try to add error Exceptions.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Comment: @touero click element xpath=//path[contains(@d,'M400 32H48A48 48 0 0 0 0 80v352a48 48 0 0 0 48 48h137.25V327.69h-63V256h63v-54.64c0-62.15 37-96.48 93.67-96.48 27.14 0 55.52 4.84 55.52 4.84v61h-31.27c-30.81 0-40.42 19.12-40.42 38.73V256h68.78l-11 71.69h-57.78V480H400a48 48 0 0 0 48-48V80a48 48 0 0 0-48-48z')] not found

Comment: The number part contained in your xpath may change. Please try to shorten it and pay attention to whether the iframe exists. If you can provide the website and specific elements, I will try to write an xpath.